# SQL 1064 in Procedures

Tags: mysql, sql, function, stored-procedures

Hey I'm leraning right now for my study Exams.
I have a Problem with Procedures and Functions.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testProc()
BEGIN
  DECLARE testNR INT;
END
```

This is my testCode but every Procedure and every Function gives me this Failure:

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
SQLState:  42000
ErrorCode: 1064
Error occurred in:
CREATE PROCEDURE testProc()
BEGIN
    DECLARE testNR INT
```

Is there something that I do wrong or do I have Problems with my IDE SQuirrel?

Comment: Use `DELIMITER` before and after the procedure declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change delimiters while creating the procedure; otherwise `;` is seen as the end of the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement.

As explained in [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html), you need to

> use[] the mysql client `delimiter` command to change the statement delimiter from `;` to `//` while the procedure is being defined. This enables the ; delimiter used in the procedure body to be passed through to the server rather than being interpreted by mysql itself. See [Section 23.1, “Defining Stored Programs”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html).

It doesn’t have to be `//`; another common choice is `$$`.

In your example, this might look like

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE testProc()
BEGIN
  DECLARE testNR INT;
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Glad to help! Please remember to select an answer! :)